# inline javascript working but not as reference

Tags: javascript

i have a block of code that handles recaptcha. when i tested it as inline it worked fine. but when i used `<script src="js.js"></script>` it didn't. i kept getting recaptcha() is not a function error message. what's more confusing is that rest of the code in js.js got executed just fine. only the recaptcha block didn't. my understanding is that src merely pulls data from the referenced location and plug it into the calling body. why didn't it work? also the script worked as inline wrapped in  so i guess the location where the script got plugged into was not the cause.

```
function recaptcha(e) {
    var action = e.target.id;
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('12345', {action: action})
        .then(function(token) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("token", token);
            fetch('recaptcha.php', {
                method: "POST", 
                body: formData
            })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then (action=>{
                switch (action) {
                    case 'login':
                        console.log('login');
                    break;
                    case 'contact':
                        console.log('contact');
                    break;
                    case 'process':
                        console,log('process');
                    break;
                    default:
                        console.log('recaptcha error');
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess at the time you're trying to access the `recaptcha()` function the js.js file you've created hasn't been processed yet. Could you try wrapping your call to the recaptcha function in a document.

```
// Listen for `DOMContentLoaded` event
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    console.log(`Document is ready!`);
    recaptcha(e);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i placed your code right after the external link to load JS and it did trigger the action. so the code did get loaded just but somehow it failed to get triggered by the form button. i will do some tests to find out more.